# submit_tag not sending to the right controller and action in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I created a form on my application that is suposed to delete some media on my app.

I have a Album entity that has some media on it. I created a partial called media_uploader so I can reuse it on other places. Im calling my partial from the albums/new view. Like this:

```
<%= render '/profiles/edit/sidebar', user: current_user %>
        <article class="col-9 col-offset-1">
          <h3 class="color-gray-medium">Album Info</h3>
          <div class="row row-no-padding top-5">
            <%= form_for @album do |f| %>
               <div class="col-9">
                 <div class="form-group row" >
                   <div class="col-6">
                    <label for="">Name:</label>
                    <%= f.text_field :name %>
                  </div>
                 </div>
               </div>
              <div class="col-9">
                 <div class="form-group row" >
                            <div class="col-6">
                              <%= render 'shared/media_uploader', media_contents: @media_contents %>
                            </div>      
                        </div>
                    </div>

shared/_media_uploader.html.erb


<%= link_to 'Delete', delete_media_path, method: :delete, id: 'delete-all', class: 'btn btn-danger', disabled: media_contents.empty? %>
        <br><br>
        <div class="row">
          <div id="media-contents" class="col-12">
            <% if media_contents.empty? %>
              <h5 id="no-media">No Media Found</h5>
            <% else %>
              <% media_contents.each do |media| %>
                <div class="col-4">
                  <div class="thumbnail">
                    <%= image_tag media.file_name_url(:thumb) %>
                    <div class="caption">
                      <p>
                        <%= check_box_tag 'media_contents[]', media.id %>
                      </p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              <% end %>
          </div>
                    </div>
                <% end %>
        <% end %>
```

My routes are like this:

```
  resources :media_contents, only: [:create]
  delete 'delete_media', to: "media_contents#delete_media"
  delete 'delete_all', to: 'media_contents#delete_all'
```

When I click on the delete button here:

```
 <%= form_tag({controller: "media_contents", action: "delete_media"}, method: "delete") do %>
              <%= submit_tag 'Delete', id: 'delete', class: 'btn btn-danger', disabled: media_contents.empty? %>
```

It gives a error:

```
No route matches [DELETE] "/albums"
```

I understand that this is caused because of the outside form_for: @album.

The question is: "How can I do this?" How can I, inside this @album form, call a method from another controller and make it works?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you routes of media_contents is limited to "create"
Adding :delete could solve the issue

```
resources :media_contents, only: [:create, :delete]
```

Also why add a custom routes for delete when DELETE action already exists for the controller?

I could be that your form_tag of **media_contents** is inside the form_tag of **albums**.
That could be one of the reasons it's calling "albums" controller

Comment: I changed it and get the same message Jijo.

Comment: I agreed with this. But how can I call this method "delete" from the partial and receive the params needed from the view?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use form inside another form, it is invalid html. But you can use 2 submit buttons and decide what to do inside the controller action, depending on `commit` parameter. You need to remove inner `form_tag` from the partial and change update action like:

```
if params[:commit] == "Delete"
  # deletion logic or redirect to needed delete action goes here
else 
  # existing `update` goes here
end
```

Comment: But using this,the parameters  <%= check_box_tag 'media_contents[]', media.id %> are coming empty. Do you know why?

Comment: @FernandoMaymone, sorry, I missed your checkboxes. Updated the answer

Comment: Hey Vasilisa. This is not the problem. The question is because Im not getting the media_contents ids on my controller. This is a print from my controller: 

{"_method"=>"delete", "authenticity_token"=>"7RdK2BvJJNeL3BumtuoauYy7KRIlGgS2cdYxlWE1BReBz+tqeAmX+sY1ZZIynvQ18L+GFwGzcXiNCGqDpXo4aw==", "controller"=>"media_contents", "action"=>"delete_media"}

Comment: @FernandoMaymone, if you use link_to, as I  suggested in the first answer, you can pass checked ids to it only with javascript. But with two submit buttons for main form (`form_for @album`) you can pass them easily to the update action and inside the action decide, what to do, depending on `commit` parameter

Comment: Hey Vasilisa. Thanks for the reply. I just updated my question. I still dont know why 'media_contents[]' are not coming in my paramethers. You are talking about what to do on the actions, but this is not the problem. My problem is that Im not getting media_contents[] on my paramethers, when inside the controller

Comment: @FernandoMaymone Misunderstanding :( You updated the question with `link_to 'Delete' ...` But the link have no idea about your checkboxes and it shouldn't. I posted the first version of the answer because I missed the checkboxes in your form and thought, that you need to delete all media contents

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185222/discussion-between-fernando-maymone-and-vasilisa).